# How can I test this in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following code:

```
const HeaderMenu = ({ location }) => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleLogout = doLogout(dispatch);
  const handleLogoutOrder = async ({ stage }) => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
    await dispatch(
      fetchRejectionReasons({
        siteId: 'USDJD',
        serviceId: 'CAR',
        stage: stage || EXIT_REASONS.EXIT
      })
    );
  };
return(
<>
      <Popup
        isModalOpen={isModalOpen}
        setIsModalOpen={setIsModalOpen}
        logout
      />
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div>
          <Link data-testid="link" to="/">
            <img src={logoUrl} />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div
          role="button"
          tabIndex="0"
          onClick={
            ORDER_ROUTES.includes(location.pathname)
              ? handleLogoutOrder 
              : handleLogout
          }
          data-testid="headermenu-logout-btn"
        >
          Logout
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
)
...
```

I don't have any idea how to test handleLogoutOrder function in Jest using react testing library.. if anyone with experience on this can help me, will be greatly appreciated.
I've tested the Popup render.. I need to test setIsModalOpen(true) and the dispatch fetch function.

Comment: With `react-testing-library` you won't be testing the implementation of your code inside components. You are testing the application from the visitors perspective. That being said, you probably want to click a button that calls the handleLogoutOrder and check if the modal is visible. With Jest and redux-mock-store you can additionally check if the `fetchRejectionReasons` is dispatched with the expected payload.

Comment: I'm already checking if the modal is visible, and it's ok, but I don't have coverage on the if statement and dispatch(fetchRejectionReasons()).. and I don't know how to test these.

Comment: I'm not seeing how the `handleLogoutOrder` is being called. But it looks to me that you should test a scenario with and without a message.

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you tell me how should I test this?

Comment: In your case, you want to mock the location or make a utility function out of `ORDER_ROUTES.includes(location.pathname)` which you can mock. I don't see where the `handleLogoutOrder` parameters are coming from, so I can't help you with that part.

Comment: I've modified the question, seems that I don't need those params (message and topMessage). I've already checked the rendering of the modal. So I'm ok there. I need to cover the setIsModalOpen(true) and the next one with dispatch(fetch..) function..

Comment: I'm a bit confused about who is who in this conversation.

Comment: I posted the question :) lol

Comment: Since your callback depends on the `location` variable, you should override that in order to be able to test both cases. You can achieve this by wrapping each test with a `MemoryRouter` and set the route to match one of the values in the `ORDER_ROUTES` array.

Comment: Yes this is the answer, I figure it out today that the location was not set correctly in the test case. Came here to post the answer and saw your solution. Thanks for your time and help.